# table join for checkbox check

Tags: php, mysql

so I am trying to auto check tick boxes by comparing the cat_id from the list of categries I am showing and the docs associated to them in the join table and auto ticking the checkboxes if the rows exist:

```
<?php

function build_cat_checkboxes(){

    global $dbc; // database connection
    global $id; // id from the url


    $q = "SELECT * FROM doc_cat_join LEFT OUTER JOIN cats ON cats.cat_id = doc_cat_join.cat_id;";
    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.

    var_dump($r);

    $currentDoc = $id;

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {

    $checked = (($row['cat_id'] == $currentDoc) ? 'checked="checked"' : '');

    echo '<ul>
          <li><label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cat_id[]" value="' . $row['cat_id'] . '" '.$checked.'"> ' . $row["cat_name"] . '</label></li>
        </ul>';
    }

    }

?>
```

Now what i am seeing is that is returns the checkbox (with no tick) by which the doc is associated too in the join table. but it isn't what I am wanting - I really could do with some pointers on this one!

[image: Image of my catagories]

this is where I want the ticks to be pre ticked if the row exists in the join table.

[image: Example of the rows in the join table]

[image]

I hope the visual help my problem...

[image]

Comment: thumbs up for afford ;-) SQL table definitions and sample data are most welcome in the form of valid `CREATE TABLE ...` and `INSERT INTO...` statements. Makes it a lot easier to fiddle with.

Comment: Any chance 1) no visuals and text output of related tables thru `show create table tblname` 2) results from query in text 3) desired results

Comment: The issue I am having to put it simply is that I need a way to check the join table while im that doc editing it to show ticks in the checkboxes if the `doc_id` and `cat_id` is a row in the `doc_cat_join` table